# Jquery Rotate IE6 Issue

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-6, jquery-rotate

Currently I am using jquery rotate plugin to rotate a image on the page, everything works fine in all browsers on my side. The problem is that our qa dept. is looking at their ie6 vm and they are not seeing the image that is rotated on the page(actually they see the image for a split second and then it dissapears. The main difference between our vm's is that they are using ie6 6.0.290 and i am using 2.0.260. I am just trying to find out from someone if they might see a problem with my code or maybe make a suggestion. Here is my jquery:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#main-image img').rotate(90);
    $('#main-image .rvml').css({ 'margin': '-65px 0 0 -105px' });

    if ($('.ie6, .ie7').length) {
        $('#main-image .photo').css({ 'overflow': 'hidden', 'height': '240px' });
        $('#main-image .rvml').css('position', 'relative');
    }

    if ($('.ie6, .ie7, .ie8').length) {
        $('#main-image img').css('visibility', 'visible');
    } else {
        $('#main-image img').fadeIn('fast');
    }
});
```

Also here is the plugin i have been using: http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

Comment: The docs say > IE 6 so maybe that's not inclusive

Comment: @austinbv: Actually, it says "IE6 >", which I read as "from IE6 and upward". The techniques it uses should work with IE6 just as well as the do with IE7 and IE8. All the same, I would counsel anyone still trying to support IE6 to stop -- it's down to less than 2% usage in most countries now; it's just not worth taking the time to get a site working with it any more (frankly, we stopped supporting IE6 over a year ago, and we're even starting to consider dropping official support for IE7 too now).

Comment: Yes I know that ie6 is on the door out and yes our traffic is about 4% for ie users but that traffic for money wise still pulls in some pretty good money . So to just turn our backs on them would be bascially saying we dont want to them go shop somewhere else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're rotating the image by 90 degrees, you can use the DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage rotation property.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532918(v=vs.85).aspx

```
#main-image img { filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=1); }
```